# Are terminated apps removed from the app switcher?

Tags: ios

If an app is suspended and the system decides to terminate it, is it removed from the app switcher or does the app switcher retain a snap shot of the app as if its still suspended?

Comment: The latter. Only when the user explicitly kills it does it vanish from the switcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stay there until the user swipes up to kill it. When the user returns to the snapshot of a killed app it will simply relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

Apps terminated by iOS are not (normally) removed from the app switcher. However, if the user swipes up on the app to remove it from the app switcher, that app is (normally) also terminated.

I say "normally" because Apple does not document this behavior and may be subject to future changes. But this is how the app switcher currently appears to behave.